# How to Make Kim Thayil of Soundgarden (Outshined) Sound

Tags: guitar

Listen to this song:

What type of equipment can make this sound?  I have a Fender Mustang I and I can get a deep, distorted sound; but there is something else going on here!

Comment: note that for large portions of that song, there are 2 guitars and a bass line which are all playing essentially the same thing. This gives it a wide stereo sound and lots of low band (especially with drop D tuning) even before you start talking about effects.

Comment: Is that what's going on in the intro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it sounds like a little bit of chorus and some deep distortion. And as per @horatio's comment, they do a fair bit of multitracking guitars which works like a chorus in fattening the sound.

Not sure which kit he is using on this track, but here's a list of the kit he uses:

First up, Kim likes Fender and Gibson guitars, having quite a range:

- Guild S-100
- Gibson Les Paul Custom Lite
- Gibson Firebird
- '57 Fender Telecaster
- Gibson SG
- Fender Jazzmaster
- Guild S-300

And he uses a wide range of amps and Cabinets:

- Mesa Electra Dyne amps (seen 2010)
- Mesa vintage Tremo-Verb 2x12 combo amps (2010)
- Mesa Boogie Stiletto 4x12" Slant cabinets (2010)
- Mesa Boogie Dual Rectifier
- Peavey VTM 120's
- Music Man HD130
- Mesa Boogie 50-watt Mavericks
- Fender Super
- Orange Head
- Fender Twin Reverb
- Fender Vibro-Kings
- Marshall Cabinets

But the core of his sound is down to the effects he uses:

- MXR MC404 CAE Crybaby Dual Inductor Wah
- Electro-Harmonix Micro POG
- MXR Doubleshot Distortion
- EHX XO Deluxe Memory Man
- Hughes & Kettner Tube Rotoshpere (MK I)
- MXR chorus
- Colorsound wah
- Jim Dunlop Rotovibe
- Mu-Tron
- Boss CE-2 Chorus pedal
- Ibanez CS-9 chorus
- DOD fx10 Bi-fet Preamp
- DOD flangers
- Mesa Switching pedals
- T-Rex Reptile pedal

Information from [Kim Thayil's Guitar Rig page on uberproaudio](http://www.uberproaudio.com/who-plays-what/270-soundgarden-kim-thayil-guitar-gear-rig-and-equipment)

Comment: Thank you, there's a lot of stuff here.  I tried adding a chorus to my combo amp + distortion but it just doesn't sound as rich!  What would you do if you were trying to replicate that sound?

Comment: @user1477388 As Metallica's *Enter Sandman*, that's probably more than one guitar you are hearing with different settings. Same with Megadeth's *I thought I knew it all*.

Comment: From what I heard, the Guild S100 is his go-to around that time. I think the S100 is mostly a Gibson SG clone, so any suitably Gibson sounding guitar should do.